# Java EE: Trying to bind interceptor via annotation with multiple values

Tags: java, logging, binding, interceptor

I have a weird problem trying to add a parameterized logging interceptor to my Java EE 7 application.

I went from a class interceptor using the @Interceptors annotation to writing a custom interceptor binding. What I have not looks like this...

The annotation

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
        ElementType.TYPE,
        ElementType.METHOD
})
public @interface LogMethodCall {

    MethodLogger logLevel() default MethodLogger.INFO;

}
```

The interceptor

```
@Slf4j
@LogMethodCall
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class ActionInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    protected Object protocolInvocation(final InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {

        log.info(
                "{}: <{}> called. Parameters={}",
                ic.getTarget().getClass().getName(),
                ic.getMethod().getName(),
                ic.getParameters());

        return ic.proceed();
    }

}
```

The usage

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{account}")
    @LogMethodCall
    public void inboxes(@Suspended AsyncResponse response, @PathParam("account") String account) {
        ...
    }
```

When I use it like this everything works OK.

Buy when I try to use change the logLevel and use

```
@LogMethodCall(logLevel=MethodLogger.DEBUG)
```

then my interceptor never gets called.

What am I missing here? Why setting the annotation value breaks the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you say that your interceptor is catching only when the value is INFO, you can consider to put your `logLevel()` attribute as @Nonbinding.

By default, qualifier arguments are considered for matching bean qualifiers to injection point qualifiers. A @Nonbinding argument is not considered for matching.

Try this:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
        ElementType.TYPE,
        ElementType.METHOD
})
public @interface LogMethodCall {

    @Nonbinding MethodLogger logLevel() default MethodLogger.INFO;

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without setting default value?